# In org-mode, how do I continue a list in a new line?

Tags: org-mode

For example:

```
* Tests
** Test1
   - When I put a new-line right here ->
the list will not be continued (unlike in word or similar applications).
```

For clarification, what I expect is:

```
* Tests
** Test1
   - When I put a command right here ->
   - the list will be continued (like in word or similar applications).
```

I am using the most recent version of spacemacs where it was possible with evil-bindings, but I deactivated them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`M-ENTER` at the end of a list item inserts a new list item. See the manual node [(org) Structure editing](https://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-editing.html).

Comment: Thanks for jumping in! But this is not what I am looking for. I put a more clear example in the question. Btw, there is a quicker way for doing what you just explained: C-j

Comment: Just saw your edit. Seems to be right.
My problem is caused by this: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/9603